# basic bootstrap4 html landing page

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a basic landing page I am designing in Bootstrap 4.  I would like the menu (header) across the top, which works.  Below that I want the main area with a background picture, and two lines of text, centered.  Easy, right?  For some reason, I cannot get the main area below the header.  I am loading these css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Here is my main header, which displays fine:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
     
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mtlNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>            
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        <div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mtlNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center"> -->
                                <li class="lead_1"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>   
                                <li class="lead_1"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                                <li class="lead_1"><a href="howWeCanHelp.html">HOW WE CAN HELP</a></li>
                                <li class="lead_1"><a href="benefits.html">BENEFITS OF SPORTS</a></li>
                                <li class="lead_1"><a href="donate.html">DONATE</a></li>                   
                                <li class="lead_1"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>                
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The last div closes the header.  Next I have:

```
<div class="demo-wrap">
    <img class="demo-bg" src="images/040.jpg">
    <div class="demo-content"></div>
        <h3>PROVIDING<span>Opportunity</span></h3>
        <p>Because all kids deserve the chance to experience the joy of sports. </p>
    </div>
</div>

        
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                
</body>
</html>
```

Here is relevant css (not what's in bootstrap 4 css):

```
.demo-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.demo-bg {
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.demo-content {
  position: relative;
}

#header .navbar-brand{
  font-size:40px;
  color:#f4f4f4;
}

#header .navbar a{
  color:#f4f4f4;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 700;
  }
#header .navbar li{
  padding-right:18px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  This seems so basic, yet I cannot get this correct.  Here is a link to what it looks like:
[main page][1]

```
[1]: http://steppingstonez.com/test/test.html
```

Comment: custom css (test css) should be under bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by removing all the CSS you have written as it will surely conflict with Bootstrap CSS. Generally with Bootstrap you're fine messing about with eye-candy and colours and theme CSS but when you begin on the `position`,`z-index`, `overflow` and even sometimes `margin` and `padding` CSS it is very easy to confuse Bootstrap.

Give this a try.....

**HTML** (Everything is nested inside a Row then a Column. On Small screens the Column will be full width but on medium screens and upwards it will be neatly centered with a good margin at the left and right).

```
<div class="row demo-wrap">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 mx-auto">
          <h3>PROVIDING<span>Opportunity</span></h3>
          <p>Because all kids deserve the chance to experience the joy of sports. </p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also try `class="text-center"` on the above `h3` and `p` tags.

**CSS** (The image that was removed from your HTML is now a CSS background of your Row and should perfectly fit across the page whilst keeping it centered).

```
.demo-wrap{
background: url(images/040.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  What I have now is the header, then a small strip (1 inch deep) of the background image and the text above it.  How do I make the background image (which is large) fill the entire page?  

I can't paste the screenshot here, but it is at www.steppingstonez.com/test/screenshot.png.